# Why does TypeScript ignore the type constraint?

Tags: typescript

We define the `get(o, key, default_value)` function that should work with any Object that satisfies the `{ get: (key: K, default_value: D) => R }` interface.

TypeScript should validate that only such objects can be passed to the `get` function.

But it also allows passing a `{ get: (key: K) => R }` object, which is wrong.

```
function get<K, D, R>(
  o: { get: (key: K, default_value: D) => R }, key: K, dvalue: D
): R {
  return o.get(key, dvalue);
}

class Params {
  constructor(public values: { [key: string]: number }) { }

  get(key: string): number | undefined {
    return this.values[key]
  }
}
const params = new Params({ a: 10 });

console.log(get(params, "a", 5))
```

Why does it ignore the constraint and allow such code to compile? And is there a way to enforce the constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because: `(key: K) => R` is a subtype of `(key: K, default_value: D) => R` so an instance of the former can be assigned to the latter type. See [comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions). When this assignment happens, it basically means *ignoring extra parameter passed to the function, which is quite common in javascript*.